# Android Fragment getItem called twice causing data not to appear?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have this problem with my Android `Fragment`. What is happening is that I have a few `Fragment`s in my `TabLayout`. I instantiate them no problem, but I run into an issue where the first time I instantiate the `Fragment`, the Fragment is created and data seems to be loaded correctly initially. However, after all the data is loaded initially, there is a second call to instantiate the `Fragment` because the `Fragment getItem(int position)` method is called once more for some reason. However, because I only initialize the data the first time around (there is a `static` variable I created in my Fragment that initializes the data for me), the `static` variable will already know that data has already been loaded properly and that it should not load data again. As a result, my loading screen seems to appear  continuously because the second time data cannot be fetched. Is there any way to get around this? Either have the fragment only instantiated once or load the data only the second and final time the `Fragment` is created? Here is my code:

```
private void setupTabLayout() {
    View layout = findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
    if (layout != null) {
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    }
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("First Fragment"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Second Fragment"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Third Fragment"));
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    if(viewPager != null) {
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

PagerAdapter.java

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
    int numTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.numTabs = numTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                //Here, the PublicTabFragment is instantiated twice,
                //causing the onResume and onCreate methods of my PublicTabFragment() 
                //to be called twice.
                PublicTabFragment tab1 = new PublicTabFragment();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                FollowersTabFragment tab2 = new FollowersTabFragment();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                ProfileTabFragment tab3 = new ProfileTabFragment();
                return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numTabs;
    }
```

PublicTabFragment:

```
private View fragmentView;
private View progressOverlay;
//Declared static so I don't have to call getPublicPostsFromDatabase twice
private static LocationService locationService;
private static Location currentLocation;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (fragmentView == null) {
        fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.posts_tab, container, false);
    }
    return fragmentView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setupLocation();
}

private void setupLocation() {
    Context context = getContext();
    //Checked once staticly so I don't have to call getPublicPostsFromDatabase twice
    if(locationService == null) {
        locationService = new LocationService(context, new LocationUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void canReceiveLocationUpdates() {

            }

            @Override
            public void cannotReceiveLocationUpdates() {
                //well we know we cant receive updates so we have to create a settings request
            }

            //update location to our servers for tracking purpose
            @Override
            public void updateLocation(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    currentLocation = location;
                    progressOverlay = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.progress_overlay);
                    progressOverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
                    swipeContainer.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary);
                    databaseQuery.getPublicPostsFromDatabase(currentLocation, progressOverlay, fragmentView, getContext(), R.id.public_posts_feed);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void updateLocationName(String localityName, Location location) {
                locationService.stopLocationUpdates();
            }
        });
        locationService.startUpdates();
    }
}
```

EDIT: I tried setting the `locationService` variable NOT to static and the getPublicPostsFromDatabase call works fine on the second time the Fragment is instantiated, but then the problem becomes that the `getPublicPostsFromDatabase` method is called twice. Even if I set a `static boolean variable` to be `true` within the `getPublicPostsFromDatabase` and only call `getPublicPostsFromDatabase` when the `static boolean variable` is `false`, the `Fragment` is instantiated a second time only after `getPublicPostsFromDatabase` finishes which will then make `getPublicPostsFromDatabase` called again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with a boolean?

```
private Boolean mLoad = false;
```

and when they are load, put him to true and for load put this condition

```
if (!mLoad) {
    ...
    mLoad = true;
}
```

Comment: I have tried with a boolean but the problem seems that the `getPublicPostsFromDatabase` is completed before the second time the `Fragment` is instantiated. As a result, `getPublicPostsFromDatabase` is called again which is not what I would want ideally. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Ritesh could you elaborate what you mean by an eventBus to manage the data loading?

Comment: event bus is dependency in which you can fire event and catch event anywhere in app, ex:-   http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/11/28/android-how-to-use-the-greenrobot-eventbus/

Answer (score 0):

Set the setOffscreenPageLimit for not load the fragment data again.so try this below line:

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(yourNooftab);
```

Comment: I don't think this would work. This is because my first tab would be loaded twice no matter what even if I set the off screen page limit to 0.